# Thymeleaf Validation error messages are getting flushed(lost) when redirecting to the View from Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to validate the user inputs of a form backed by spring-boot and thymeleaf. Pattern Validator is present on the Model attribute and after capturing the errors inside the Controller, I am redirecting to the View.

**Inside the openConfigurationForm.html th:error is never getting evaluated and there is no alert on the html view rendered in the end.**

```java
// Model  
public class ConfigurationParameters {

    @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}$", message = "Invalid UUID")
    private String userId;

// other fields, getters and setters

}
```

```java
//Controller
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = { "/testtool" })
public class TestToolApp {

@PostMapping(value = ("/openConfiguration")
public ModelAndView openConfiguration(@ModelAttribute @Valid ConfigurationParameters configurationParameters, Errors errors) {

        // In case of Validation Errors
        if(errors.hasErrors()) {
            ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("testtool/openConfigurationForm");
            ConfigurationParameters configParams = new ConfigurationParameters(testToolConfig);
            model.addObject("configurationParameters", configParams);

            return model;
        }

//...}

}
```

//View - openConfigurationForm.html

```html
<form id="params" action="#" th:action="@{openConfiguration}" th:object="${configurationParameters}" method="post">
<label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" size="36" maxlength="36" name="userId" th:field="*{userId}">
    <p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('userId')}" th:errors="*{userId}" class="alert"></p>
</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The ModelAttribute which I am working on is "configurationParameters". I had to align this to @ModelAttribute annotation in the function call...

I changed the signature of the method call openConfiguration() to:

public ModelAndView openConfiguration( **@ModelAttribute ("configurationParameters")** @Valid ConfigurationParameters configurationParameters, Errors errors)

instead of :

public ModelAndView openConfiguration(**@ModelAttribute** @Valid ConfigurationParameters configurationParameters, Errors errors)